# How to collate multiple files in AWK?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to collate a series of `.csv` log files that are named by date (e.g., `2019-02-24.csv`). There are a bunch of them, so I'm trying to script the process. I've crafted an `AWK` script that combines individual files:

```
awk ' FNR==1 { while (/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFICE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-01.csv >> usage_history.csv
```

But I am failing when I try to string the `AWK` commands together with a control loop in BASH:

```
for i in {01..28}; do echo "awk ' FNR==1 { while (/\"_time\",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-$i.csv >> user_history.csv"; done
```

When I run this, it prints out the correct commands to the command line, but the `awk` scripts are not executed (they only get printed). If I run it without `echo`, I get errors telling me that the file doesn't exist; though all files are present:

```
bash: awk ' FNR==1 { while (/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-01.csv >> user_history.csv: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing in my loop?

---

Here is a condensed sample of the command and  the error messages:

```
$ for i in {01..02}; do "awk ' FNR==1 { while (/\"_time\",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-$i.csv >> user_history.csv"; done
bash: awk ' FNR==1 { while (/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-01.csv >> user_history.csv: No such file or directory
bash: awk ' FNR==1 { while (/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/) getline; } 1 { print } ' 2019-01-02.csv >> user_history.csv: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Good that you have shown what you have tried to solve this problem. Could you please post sample of input and sample of output in your post in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: @double-beep changed title to "How to collate multiple files in AWK", hopefully a little better. It did look a bit vague when I stepped back from it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 2019-01-[0-9]*.csv >> user_history.csv
```

***Here following are the points*** why one could use this approach:

1- Use of `for` loop and calling `awk` command in that each time will be a overkill. We should use smart approach when `awk` could read multiple files then we should sue it.

2- Now comes the `getline` part which you tried in your code, so if we want to negate any string then simply negate it by using `!/string_to_be_skipped/` so it will look for only those lines which are NOT having this string.

3- While mentioning file(multiple files) to single `awk` command I used `2019-01-[0-9]*.csv` why because since you have NOT told if files will be created daily basis or not so in case we give it a loop style and that specific file is NOT present then we will get an error. For an example let's say I use following awk command where I intentionally removed file named(`2019-01-02.csv`).

```
awk '........' 2019-01-{01..29}.csv
awk: cannot open 2019-01-02.csv (No such file or directory)
```

So to avoid these kind of situations I have used `2019-01-[0-9]*.csv` where it will only look for files which have digits after `2019-01-0` and will loop NOT run in a loop and complaint us that some xyz etc file is  missing.

Comment: does putting the 'day' numbers in square brackets ensure that the files will be picked up in order? I originally used curly brackets with the partial ellipsis ```{01..09}``` because I understood that to mean that it would iterate through the files in order ```(e.g., 01 then 02 then 03 etc.)```. I believe that the square brackets ```[01-09]``` would mean that any number will match, right?

Comment: Yes it means any number will match but giving in brackets like I showed in my post means it will look for 1 to 29 as shown in example. Please go through my explanation once too.

Comment: Got it. YES! This works well. Please look at your first code block, I think there is an extra zero before the bracket - I changed it to this -- ```awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 2019-01-[0-3][1-9].csv >> user_history.csv```

Comment: I am building some test files so I can be more thorough (my files have hundreds or thousands of entries in each csv; too much scrolling...

Comment: I made a final tweak to your suggestion so that the script will handle multiple days, months, and years (only 2018 and 2019 in this case). Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for your help and conversation - it was very informative.

Comment: Up1 for your patience. Throw error or not can be a feature, and can be used as a debugging way for other mistakes. It's better to state the difference clearly: that {01..29} will throw error and stop executing while `[0-9]*` won't but will match extra files if exist. And `[0-9]*` will read files in different order. The OP's own tweak one avoided the reading order problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in {01..28}; do awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 2019-01-$i.csv >>user_history.csv;done
```

The commands after `do` should not be quoted.
And what you were doing essentially equals to ignore the title lines.
The `{print}` after `1` is unnecessary -- single `1` implies `{print}`. The `1` is to provide a `true`.
-- When there's only an expression but no block, the block implies to {print}.
-- And only a regexp equals `$0~/regex/`, and here I negated it.

If there's no other command inside the loop, you can simplify the loop with one `awk` command:

```
awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 2019-01-{01..28}.csv >>user_history.csv
```

But this one will throw error and stop executing when one of the files not existed.

Another way is:

```
awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 2019-01-[0-3][0-9].csv >>user_history.csv
```

This one will only match filenames, instead of loop for them.
It won't stop executing nor throw error, So if there's file missing you wouldn't know. And it will match extra files if exist.
For example it will read `2019-01-34.csv` if it exists.

So if you want the warnings (warnings won't affect the results), but don't want the commands to stop, then use the first `for` loop one.

Pitfalls:
`[0-3][1-9]` won't match `10`,`20` and `30`, but will match `32` to `39`.
`[0-9]*` will match any longer number, but with `20` to `29` before `3` or likewise, it's string order.

Comment: Perfect; thanks @Tiw. So I was messing up my awk commands by having it in double quotes. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: I inadvertently unchecked your answer while I was clicking around on this page. My apologies - no slight intended; both you and RavinderSingh13 were instrumental in helping me out.

Comment: @AFK  Updated the answer to show you the upsides and downsides for each way. Since you're already making good progress, I guess some or all of them you might already know, anyway I think it's good to add them, at least it's good for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tiw and @RavinderSingh13 for their guidance. Here is the final awk script that is working well for my case where I have daily files from multiple days, months, and years (only 2018 and 2019 in this case):

> awk '!/"_time",PIN,FULLNAME,OFFCODE,Acronym,Name/' 201[8-9]-[0-1][0-2]-[0-3][0-9].csv >> user_history.csv